# chomp giving me 1's and 0's

Tags: perl

I have two pieces of code. The first one is what I wanted. BUt why is it the second one is giving me 1's and 0's (is my english correct, or is it "1s and 0s") and not "johnchrismandy".

```
foreach (@data) {
    print ;
}
//output
john
chris
mandy
```

```
foreach  (@data) {
    print chomp ;
}
//output
110
```

UPDATE:: 
Thank you guys, I understand it more now.
But I don't understand the last part of the doc.

=>
You can actually chomp anything that's an lvalue, including an assignment:
    chomp($cwd = pwd);

Comment: What did http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html tell you `chomp` returns?

Comment: @Wooble You have the correct answer!

Comment: ty guys for the doc reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) behaviour: "It returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments." You want

```
for (@data) {
   chomp;
   print "$_\n";
}
```

Note that `$_` is aliased to the element of `@data`, so `@data` is getting modified too. If you don't want that to happen.

```
for (@data) {
   my $item = $_;
   chomp($item);
   print "$item\n";
}
```

---

About the last line of the docs:

`my $item = $_;` returns `$item` as an lvalue (a value suitable for the ***l***eft-hand side of an assignment). As such,

```
my $item = $_;
chomp($item);
```

can be written as

```
chomp( my $item = $_ );
```

Comment: I don't understand the last part of the doc. => You can actually chomp anything that's an lvalue, including an assignment:
    chomp($cwd = `pwd`);

Comment: @airnet, Added explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are printing the return value of the `chomp` function and this is the total number of characters removed from all its arguments

Answer (score 1):

[chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) returns the total number of character removed.

So it prints how many `\n` it has removed.

Do it in the following way:

```
foreach  (@data) {
    chomp($_);
    print $_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, chomp returns the number of characters removed.  In my particular instance (regex with eval modifier in a one-line perl replace-in-file statement), I needed to get the chomped value in a single statement without having a separate print statement.  I finally found a working solution - wrapping the chomp command in an if statement.

Starting with:

```
$in = "I have COMMITS commits in my log";
$in =~ s/COMMITS/`git log | grep -i '^commit' | wc -l`/e;
print $in;
```

This returns:

```
I have 256
 commits in my log
```

Great, I need to chomp this, so I try:

```
$in = "I have COMMITS commits in my log";
$in =~ s/COMMITS/chomp `git log | grep -i '^commit' | wc -l`/e;
print $in;
```

But this throws an error:

```
Can't modify quoted execution (``, qx) in chomp at ./script line 4, near "`git log | grep -i '^commit' | wc -l`}"
Execution of ./script aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Yeesh, so I need to assign the output to a local var and chomp it:

```
$in = "I have COMMITS commits in my log";
$in =~ s/COMMITS/chomp (my $VAR = `git log | grep -i '^commit' | wc -l`)/e;
print $in;
```

But as we said, chomp returns # of characters stripped:

```
I have 1 commits in my log
```

Then I found that I could wrap it in an if statement and get it to return the result, chomped:

```
$in = "I have COMMITS commits in my log";
$in =~ s/COMMITS/if (chomp (my $VAR = `git log | grep -i '^commit' | wc -l`)) { $VAR }/e;
print $in;
```

Finally, I get the command result, chomped, in one statement:

```
I have 256 commits in my log
```